# MySQL - Attendance model for Sports team

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to search for answer for over a day, but with no staisfying results.
I would like to build site to track attendace of our players on trainings and matches. All attendance systems I found so far were pretty simple - usually two tables (students, attendance). But I think that I need more complex solution for my project.

Here are some hints:
We have trainings on many schools. At each school there is many training lessons during week.
Each training lesson is for one team, but the team has more than 1 training lesson during week and usualy has them on different schools.
Each team has players and players can be part of multiple teams.
Player can attend just some training lessons - for example for team1 - MondayTraining, TuesdayTraining but not FridayTraining and for team2 just ThursdayTraining.
Attendance will manage coaches. One coach can have more than 1 team.

The main goal is to have website where Coach can see in calendar his trainings for that day and when he click the link in calendar new page with list of players who should be attending on this lesson will be opened - ideally with checkboxes or radio buttons for tracking attendance.

EDIT: here is my basic model, but I know its horrible

my try on model

[image]

Hope someone can help me with database model.

Thanks for your answers.